# Suspicious pointer conversion warning while assigning const value to a pointer why?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
     int const anila=10;
     int *ptr=&anila;
     clrscr();
     printf("%d",*ptr);
     getch();
     return 0;
}
```

why the warning occurs in the program? what is suspicious pointer conversion here? and *ptr=&anila; *ptr will have the address of anila. how it prints 10 correctly?

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to integer not a pointer to `const int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that warning is so that the compiler can warn you that you do not accidentally modify the variable `anila`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int const anila=10;
     int *ptr=&anila;
     *ptr = 100; // --> This should not be done since you declare anila as const
     printf("%d",*ptr);
     return 0;
}
```

The above code works [fine](http://ideone.com/f3wa9d) when you as a programmer did not want something like this to happen (i.e. Modifying a variable marked as read-only). Do this and the code will not compile:

```
 int const anila=10;
 int const *ptr=&anila;
```

> prog.c:6:6: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*ptr’
>
> *ptr = 100;

Also please know that `conio.h` is non-standard.

Comment: why conio.h is non standard @al_Acme please explain me.

Comment: @AnilaChandran - `conio.h` is a C header file used mostly by `MS-DOS` compilers (like Turbo C) to provide console input/output. It is not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it defined by POSIX. You can use `getchar()` for halting the screen which is there in `stdio.h`

Comment: *ptr=&anila; what happens in this line? is address of anila stored? then it has to print the address of anila. But it prints 10 correctly how?

Comment: @AnilaChandran - Yes address gets stored. it is not a syntax/compilation error. But it is a programmer's mistake to allow such a thing to happen - hence you get a warning.

Comment: if *ptr holds the address of anila means, while printing the *ptr why it is printing 10 instead of the anila's address? please explain me @al-Acme

Comment: `*ptr` does *NOT* hold the address of `anila` - `ptr` holds the address of `anila` - `*ptr` dereferences to get the value held at that address (`ptr == &anila`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51353/discussion-between-anila-chandran-and-al-acme)

Answer (score 3):

`anila` is `const`, but `ptr` is a non-`const` pointer, think about this code:

```
*ptr = 42;
```

It's trying to modify `*ptr`, i.e, `anila` here, that's why there's a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the address of `const int` to the pointer to `int`. The pointer should be to `const int` too - this should get rid of the warning.